# Sending Firebase notification with PHP

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

everyone! I am having a problem using PHP to send FIrebase notification. When I send it from Firebase console, I get the notification, but when I send it from PHP, I don't receive any notification.

DO you have any idea what is the problem?

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$message = 'ojlaasdasdasd';
$title = 'ojla';
$path_to_fcm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';    $server_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5LnDZO2BpC2aoPMshfKwRbJAJfZL8C33qRxxxxxxxxxxxxL6';
$key = 'eqnlxIQ1SWA:APA91bGf1COAZamVzT4onl66_lEdE1nWfY7rIADcnt9gtNYnw7iWTwa7AYPYTHESFholkZ89ydCQS3QeL-lCIuiWTXiqoDREO0xhNdEYboPvqg8QsBYkrQVRlrCLewC4N-hHUja1NG4f';
$headers = array(
                'Authorization:key=' .$server_key,
                'Content-Type: application/json');

$fields = array
            (
                'to'        => $key,
                'notification'  => array('title' => $title,'body' => $message)
            );


$payload = json_encode($fields);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, '$path_to_fcm' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);


?>
```

I don't get any echo from the server

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this code.Its working fine for me.just change key and token

```
<?php
define('API_ACCESS_KEY','Api key from Fcm add here');
 $fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
 $token='235zgagasd634sdgds46436';

     $notification = [
            'title' =>'title',
            'body' => 'body of message.',
            'icon' =>'myIcon', 
            'sound' => 'mySound'
        ];
        $extraNotificationData = ["message" => $notification,"moredata" =>'dd'];

        $fcmNotification = [
            //'registration_ids' => $tokenList, //multple token array
            'to'        => $token, //single token
            'notification' => $notification,
            'data' => $extraNotificationData
        ];

        $headers = [
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);


        echo $result;
```

Comment: Thank you! 'icon' where do you have stored myIcon? 
is 'icon' field an icon that shows when you swipe down notification bar, because when I swipe down I don't have any icon next to the notification

Comment: that is not needed .app developer will handle it.if its helped please vote and mark answer as accepted

Comment: android developer can customise notifcation based on reuqirement

Comment: @iCoders I implemented your fix and it seems to work! However, everytime I send a single push notification the badge counter appears at 2. It doesn't increase either. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following function to send a HTTP Request to Firebase:

```
function request($url, $body, $method = "POST", $header = "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n")
{
    switch ($method) {
        case 'POST':
        case 'GET':
        case 'PUT':
        case 'DELETE':
            break;
        default:
            $method = 'POST';
            break;
    }
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => "$header",
            'method' => "$method",
            'content' => $body
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
    return $data;
}
```

To execute the function I use the following code:

```
$fcm_key = "";
$body = array("data" => $data, "to" => "$fcm_token");

$body = json_encode($body);
$json = request("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", $body, "POST", "Authorization: key=$fcm_key\r\nContent-Type:application/json");
```

For me, this code works without any problems. Be sure that you use the right FCM device token (`$fcm_token`) and set the right FCM key (`$fcm_key`).

Answer (score 0):

```
                $tokenID = $valueTwo["TokenID"];
                $cmMessage = array();
                $cmMessage["type"] = 3;
                $cmMessage["receiverMail"] = $receiverMail;
                $cmMessage["ownerMail"] = $ownerMail;
                $cmMessage["jsonData"] = $jsonData;




                $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

                $title = "";
                $body = "";
                //$notification = array('title' => $title, 'body' => null, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');
                $arrayToSend = array('to' => $tokenID, 'priority' => 'high', 'data' => $cmMessage);
                $json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
                $headers = array();
                $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
                $headers[] = 'Authorization: key=' . $serverKey;
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
                //Send the request
                $response = curl_exec($ch);
                //Close request
                if ($response === FALSE) {
                    die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
                }
                curl_close($ch);
```

Get your server key and token id to send write them... Dont use notification tag...Like I did in code... Cuz if you write notification tag, Application in background is not got receive msg  Cuz notification tag executes on foreground and in background automatic notification is displayed..

Answer (score 0):

**Send firebase push notification via php to android, ios**

```
    function sendPushNotification($to = '', $data = array()){
    
        $api_key = '';
        $fields = array('to' => $to, 'notification' => $data);
    
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type:application/json',
            'Authorization:key='.$api_key
        );
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
    
    
    
    
    $to = ''; //Device token 
    // You can get it from FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    $message = array(
    'title' => 'Hai',
    'body' => 'New Message');
    
    echo sendPushNotification($to, $message);
```