# How to get push notifications in flutter, when database(MySQL) table change (insert, update, delete) occurs?

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I know how to create a simple notification in Flutter app , but I want to create a real time push notification whenever database(Mysql) table will update/change. I'm using PHP to send/get data from MYSQL database table. Is there any way to get notify the user when there is a change/update in database specific table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebase Cloud Messaging https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

You can call the API via PHP. Here is the example [Sending Firebase notification with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46454398/sending-firebase-notification-with-php)