# Using Firebase to push notification from WordPress to Ionic APP

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, firebase, woocommerce

I am trying to push a notification from a plugin using firebase so that the notification is received by the android app.
I have the API key from google but don’t know how to get the device token so that I can push notification using CURL.
This is a post from [Sending Firebase notification with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46454398/sending-firebase-notification-with-php) I have been following but stuck in device token. How can I get it?

This what the link mentioned above has recommended:

```
<?php
    $message = 'ojlaasdasdasd';
    $title = 'ojla';
    $path_to_fcm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';    $server_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5LnDZO2BpC2aoPMshfKwRbJAJfZL8C33qRxxxxxxxxxxxxL6';
    $key = 'eqnlxIQ1SWA:APA91bGf1COAZamVzT4onl66_lEdE1nWfY7rIADcnt9gtNYnw7iWTwa7AYPYTHESFholkZ89ydCQS3QeL-lCIuiWTXiqoDREO0xhNdEYboPvqg8QsBYkrQVRlrCLewC4N-hHUja1NG4f';
    $headers = array(
                    'Authorization:key=' .$server_key,
                    'Content-Type: application/json');
    
    $fields = array
                (
                    'to'        => $key,
                    'notification'  => array('title' => $title,'body' => $message)
                );
    
    
    $payload = json_encode($fields);
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, '$path_to_fcm' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to enable subscription to a topic by the device. The below code will subscribe the users to the topic named "ALL-USERS".

Now while sending messages using CURL, use the 'to' field as '/topics/ALL-USERS'!

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("ALL-USERS").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
    sharedPref.setSubscibeNotif(task.isSuccessful());
}});
```